# Can Parallel Universes exist?

Tags: cosmology, universe

I saw Stephen Hawking say that there are an infinity of [parallel universes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_universe). How did he get to that theory, and is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible unless you can prove it's impossible. But the very notion of parallel universes which cannot 'talk' to each other makes disproving their existence about as easy - and perhaps more philosophically akin - to [dis]proving the existence of God.